# Supergraphs and their Feynman rules

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, feynman-diagrams

I am reading *[Ideas and Methods of Supersymmetry and Supergravity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750305061)*, and have two confusions on using supergraphs, and applying the Feynman rules.

---

As an *example* of the conceptual issue I have, a result obtained for a one loop amplitude involving a chiral superfield reads,

$$\mathcal M \sim \int\frac{\mathrm d^4p}{(2\pi)^4} \left\{ \left[ \int \frac{\mathrm d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{1}{k^2-m^2}\frac{1}{(p-k)^2-m^2}\right]\left[ \int \mathrm d^4 \theta \, \color{red}{\bar\Phi(-p,\theta)\Phi(p,\theta)}\right] \right\}$$

which involves the chiral superfield itself, $\Phi$ (Fourier transformed over $x$). In normal quantum field theory, the actual field never appears in the amplitude. How does one extract from this expression a result to find say, a cross section?

---

My second related concern is, is there a correspondence between the supergraph calculations and the Feynman graphs evaluated in terms of the component fields?

I feel like I am not interpreting the supergraphs correctly in some way and would like my confusions cleared up as it seems they're not the same as evaluating ordinary Feynman diagrams.